# Bound a JSON object to JavaBean class in Spring MVC, I have some things unclear

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-mvc, jaxb

in this period I am studying the Spring MVC showcase example.

About the request mapping I have a litle doubt, I have the following situation:

In a view I submit a form, submitting this form start the following Jquery function:

```
$("form.readJsonForm").submit(function() {          

    var form = $(this);                 // Variabile che si riferisce all'elemento nel DOM che ha scatenato l'evento submit (il form) 
    var button = form.children(":first");       // Seleziona il bottone submit 

    var data = form.hasClass("invalid") ?       // OPERATORE CONDIZIONALE: il form ha classe "invalid" ? 
            "{ \"foo\": \"bar\" }" :            // SI: foo = bar 
            "{ \"foo\": \"bar\", \"fruit\": \"apple\" }";   // NO: foo= bar ; fruit = apple 


    /* AJAX CALL PARAMETER:
       type: Say to the servlet tath the request is a POST HTTP Request
       url: The address to which to send the call   
       data: the content of my data variable
       contentType: an object having JSON format
       dataType: the type of content returned by the server
    */
    $.ajax({ type: "POST", url: form.attr("action"), data: data, contentType: "application/json", dataType: "text", 
        success: function(text) { MvcUtil.showSuccessResponse(text, button); }, 
        error: function(xhr) { MvcUtil.showErrorResponse(xhr.responseText, button); }});

    return false;
});
```

So in my case is generated the following JavaScript Object having JSON format:

**{ \"foo\": \"bar\", \"fruit\": \"apple\" }**

Ok, then my Jquery function do an AJAX call and send my JSON object to the Spring controller class.

This is the method that handles this HTTP Request:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/mapping/consumes", method=RequestMethod.POST, consumes=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public @ResponseBody String byConsumes(@RequestBody JavaBean javaBean) {
    System.out.println("foo: " + javaBean.getFoo() + " fruit: " + javaBean.getFruit());
    return "Mapped by path + method + consumable media type (javaBean '" + javaBean + "')";
}
```

This method handles HTTP POST Request towards the URL: "/mapping/consumes" and consumes a JSON object (this is specify by **consumes=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE**)

Ok this method take an input parameter that is annoted using the @RequestBody annotation that indicates that my method parameter should be bound to the value in the body of the HTTP Request (my JSON object)

JavaBean class contain only 2 property that are:

```
private String foo;
    private String fruit;
```

(as the JSON object properties)

To bound the JSON object properties with the JavaBean propertis, the JavaBean class is annoted by the **@XmlRootElement** annotation:

package org.springframework.samples.mvc.mapping;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

```
@XmlRootElement
public class JavaBean {

private String foo = "bar";
    private String fruit = "apple";

    // Setter and Getter method for properties
```

Now I know that when you see an @RequestBody annotation on an object in a Spring controller, and the consumes attribute of the @RequestMapping annotation is "application/xml" (or pre spring 3.1 the Content-Type header is set to "application/xml") this will tell Spring that the payload of the request message is XML and needs to be unmarshalled to the object that was annotated with @RequestBody. In this case the object that was annotated with @RequestBody will typically be annotated itself with JAXb annotations to provide the meta data needed to marshal and unmarshal that object to/from XML, and @XmlRootElement is one of those annotations providing that metadata.

Ok, this is all clear for me...my only doubt is related to the fact that in my **@RequestMapping** annotation I have not that the **Content-Type header** is set to **"application/xml** but I have: **consumes=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE**

So I have the following question for you:

1) What is the difference between **Content-Type header** and **consumes=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE**

2) From what I understand reading the ** @XmlRootElement** documentation: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlRootElement.html

this annotation provides two-way association between XML content and content JAVA.
So I can map the content of XML fields in Java class properties, and conversely

The problem is thath in this case I have not an XML "object" but I am using a JSON object that is an alternative to XML !!! What am I missing?

Thank you very much

Andrea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First to answer your question:

> What is the difference between Content-Type header and consumes=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE?

They both define a content type but they are used for different purposes.

- A Content-Type header is part of the HTML spec; it is a property transmitted as part of the header of a HTML message which tells the receiver the format of the data payload being transmitted.
- The "consumes" annotation used on a Spring controller provides a mechanism to restrict the content types which will be accepted by your controller.  By setting your controller to `consumes=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE` you are telling your controller to only accept messages from callers which specify that they are sending JSON formatted payloads to it.  This means that you need to make sure your client code specifies a content type of 'application/json' but based on your example code it appears that has been properly set. (*Note that the consumes annotation matches content types for methods rather than 'restricts' them but for the purposes of your question I am simplifying things.  For more info see [this](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-requestmapping-consumes) link.*)

And in regards to the second question/issue:

Your code makes it appear that you are on the right track to use Spring 3.0+ to marshall your JSON message into the associated Java object, but you may need to make sure that your Spring configuration is set up properly.  Make sure you have the `<mvc:annotation-driven/>` set in your spring configuration which will includes Jackson support needed for JSON and/or XML marshalling/unmarshalling in Spring MVC (i.e. it makes sure Jackson is on your classpath).  See [this](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-annotation-driven) for details.

Also I would drop the `@XmlRootElement` tag as that is used for XML marshalling/unmarshalling and is not needed when communicating using JSON.  (It should just be ignored but I would drop it if it's truly not needed).

Lastly I'm not sure if you were using the class name 'JavaBean' for illustration purposes in your question or in your actual code, but if you are using that in your code I recommend changing the name.  The term 'JavaBean' is already used in multiple places in Java and it might be confusing to have a class with the same name.

Comment: Its quite common to produce both XML and JSON from the same URL endpoint by specifying a `ContentNegotiatingViewResolver` bean (look it up). So the XML annotations are there for the XML marshalling but not needed for JSON marshalling as Bionic_Geek said.